# v-model binding in IE11, vuejs 2

Tags: vuejs2

I have an authentication form which works fine on chrome, firefox and edge.

```
  <el-form :model="auth">
    <el-form-item class="form-item" label="Email">
      <el-input v-model="auth.email" placeholder="Email"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item class="form-item" label="Password">
      <el-input type="password" v-model="auth.password" prop="password"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-button class="submit-button" type="primary" @click="signIn">Login</el-button>
  </el-form>
```

When enter is pressed, the signIn function is called and which return sends the auth object - The login is successful which is the usual case.
In IE11 browser, the password value is always empty that is

```
{"email":"someEmail@example.com", password:"" }
```

The above object is sent as request when enter key is pressed.

Is there any polyfill for this or am I missing something for IE11 in vuejs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using [Element](http://element.eleme.io) and I don't see any `prop` attribute in the documentation for inputs.  Since native HTML inputs don't have a `prop` attribute either, IE11 could be having an issue with the password input because it doesn't know what to do with `prop="password"`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing prop attribute, I removed prop, tried again and it did not help.

Comment: I added @keyup.enter.native="signIn" in the el-form tag and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Added `@keyup.enter.native="signIn"` in the `el-form` tag and it works.